# Unity - Loading image using www cause all images in application to change

Tags: image, unity-game-engine, loadimage

I am pretty new to Unity, so this might be an easy one.

I am trying to load and image from a URL an into an image in my application. In my application I have many different images, but for some reason all the images change to the image loaded from my url.

I have made a component called `LoadImage` and added it only to the one image I want to change. My code for loading the image looks like this:

```c#
public class LoadImage : MonoBehaviour 
{

    public Image img; 

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        DownloadViaURL();
    }

    void DownloadViaURL()
    {
        Debug.Log("Called DownloadViaURL");
        FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance
           .GetReference("Child1").Child("Child2").Child("ImageURL")
           .GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task => 
           {
               Debug.Log("Default Instance entered");
               if (task.IsFaulted)
               {
                   Debug.Log("Error retrieving data from server");
               }
               else if (task.IsCompleted)
               {
                   DataSnapshot snapshot = task.Result;

                   string data_URL = snapshot.GetValue(true).ToString();

                   //Start coroutine to download image
               StartCoroutine(AccessURL(data_URL));
               }
           });
    }

    IEnumerator AccessURL(string url)
    {
        using (WWW www = new WWW(url))
        {
            yield return www;
                 www.LoadImageIntoTexture(img.mainTexture as Texture2D);
            Debug.Log("Texture URL: " + www.url);
        }
    }  
}
```

And I have then added the image as the public Image img;

Can anyone tell my why unity load the image into all imageviews in my application instead of just the one?

Comment: Maybe because you're using the same target Texture2D?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say

> I have many different images,

but I guess you mean different `Image` components where you very probably referenced the same texture from your assets multiple times

So what your code actually does is overwriting whatever texture asset is referenced by your image => it is also changed in all other images/materials etc that reference the same texture asset.

You should rather create a new texture, load the data into it and change the image's texture reference:

```c#
// Create new texture
// Size values don't matter because texture will be overwritten
var newTexture = new Texture2D(2,2);

// Load image I new texture
www.LoadImageToTexture(newTexture);

// Use the reference to that new texture
img.mainTexture = newTexture;
```

Comment: Oh I get your point and I think you are correct! But I get an error on last line: "Property or Indexer Image.mainTexture cannot be assigned to --- It is read only" - I have tried material.mainTexture but this give me the same problem as I had in the beginning (loading image in all Image components)

Comment: Doesn't matter - Solved it by creating a Sprite. Thank you so much for your help!